# What mock frameworks work with cppunit?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, cppunit

I'm in the middle of implementing a unit test infrastructure for a large `C++` project, and due to political reasons I'm almost sure [`CppUnit`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page) will be pushed as the unit testing framework.

I'm trying to identify mock frameworks that blend with [CppUnit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page). I've found [mockpp](http://mockpp.sourceforge.net/index-en.html), and I've heard that [`Google Mock`](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) should work.

What frameworks work alongside [`CppUnit`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page)?

Answer (score 2):

Mocking libraries are typically independent of the unit testing framework.  They accomplish two different jobs, and frankly don't have much reason to talk to each other.  Where they do integrate is in answering these questions:

- When should I create my mock objects?
- When should I initialize the mock objects with my expectations?
- When should I validate the mocks were called as expected?

And you do that at the appropriate points in your tests.

For one example, check opmock.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/opmock/

According to their wiki, opmock is easily called from a CppUnit test. See http://sourceforge.net/p/opmock/wiki/Using%20Opmock%20with%20other%20unit%20testing%20frameworks/

Comment: Well they actually have a very good reason to talk with each other. For example to set expectations in a mock/stub/spy (like should a mocked method return true or false). And also to read information from the mock, like how often it is called for example.

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg , the unit tests have a dependency on both the testing framework and the mocking framework. But the mock frameworks are usually independent of the testing frameworks, and vice versa.